# Reshaping dataframe - turning rows into columns based on Group

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R and need some help with reshaping some data.

Currently, the data looks like this:

| Column A | Column B | type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 | Type 1 | Date 1 |
| 20 | 20 | Type 2 | Date 1 |
| 30 | 30 | Type 1 | Date 2 |
| 40 | 50 | Type 2 | Date 2 |

And the goal is to get

| Type 1-A | Type 2-A | Type 1-B | Type 2-B | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 15 | 20 | Date 1 |
| 30 | 40 | 30 | 50 | Date 2 |

It looks fairly simple, but I have been stuck for a few days. Any help would appreciated!

Since I am still new, I am not really sure where to start. The data comes from a datascraper I made which runs every hour. I think it would have been great if I reshaped the data in the very first data pull. However, I now have several hundreds of hours of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr::pivot_wider` you could do:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
  "Column A" = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L),
  "Column B" = c(15L, 20L, 30L, 50L),
  type = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2"),
  Date = c("Date 1", "Date 1", "Date 2", "Date 2")
)

library(tidyr)

dat |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from = type,
    values_from = -c(type, Date),
    names_glue = "{type}-{gsub('Column ', '', .value)}"
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   Date   `Type 1-A` `Type 2-A` `Type 1-B` `Type 2-B`
#>   <chr>       <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#> 1 Date 1         10         20         15         20
#> 2 Date 2         30         40         30         50
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reshape`.

```
> reshape(dat, idvar='Date', timevar='type', direction='wide')
    Date Column.A.Type 1 Column.B.Type 1 Column.A.Type 2 Column.B.Type 2
1 Date 1              10              15              20              20
3 Date 2              30              30              40              50
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Column.A = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L), Column.B = c(15L, 
20L, 30L, 50L), type = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2"
), Date = c("Date 1", "Date 1", "Date 2", "Date 2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```